# How to get properties definition from an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have an interface like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get it's definition in code?

ex: property name, property type, and is property optional...etc

Comment: Types are a compile-time artifact; they do not exist at run time. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Object.keys() pass the reference of the interface you will get all the properties name

Comment: How would Object.keys() help here? You cannot use an interface as a value, is this something you tried and verified it works? @Sreemat

Comment: Object.keys() does not work for interfaces. I'm trying to do something similar, but I can't seem to find any way to do it. It's quite annoying because it means I have to duplicate the information; I essentially have to have an array of the property names as well as having them in the interface, which is just begging for someone to not notice or forget and edit it in only one place. I don't suppose there's a way I can build the interface from some other structure that will exist at runtime?